# count total gender per unique user id

Tags: python, pandas

i have data like this

[image]

I need to get descriptive statistics. I'm currently using this code:

```
df.describe(exclude = np.number)
```

and its returns like this
[image]

this is something wrong where the unique count is 5464 but the user_gender male has  55775 freq. this should not be like this. how to return the correct number?

Comment: hmmm, it seems you want compare apples with pears. Because there is `5464 unique values in column user_id` and `55775 values in column user_gender`

Comment: the unique value in ```user_id``` has no relationship with the frequency in the ```user_gender``` column

Comment: aah i see. so user_gender have relationship with user_id not unique user_id?

Comment: @lilpearce The ```.describe``` method gives us the descriptive statistics of individual columns without taking into account any kind of relationship between different columns. In this case the data is categorical, so it is gives us statistics like ```top``` (most frequently occurring), ```freq``` (how many times the ```top``` category occurs) and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The freq is the most common value’s frequency. So, in `user_gender` the top value which is the 'male' it appears 55775 times in the dataset, which looks normal because the dataset has 81948 rows.

On the other hand, is not meaningful to compare the unique number of `user_id`  and freq of `user_gender`column.

Everything looks normal :-)